# CSS Floating Of Linked Images

Tags: css, image, css-float

I can't figure out why this happens. The second image is somehow located below the level of the first one, but the next lines of images are OK.
Screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/e1P2t.jpg

The code for each linked image is :

```
<a style="display: block; float: left; padding: 5px;" target="_blank" href="_link_">
 <img src="_link_" width="300" height="200" />
</a>
```

What should I do to correct this?
Live example can be found here `http://chemica.ru/thread/1433`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to stackoverflow...

You have `<br/>` tags after each linked image. If you get rid of those, that should help.

Comment: Ah, thank you. Didn't notice it myself. I'll use regex to cut <br/> between them.

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of the `<br>` between the `<a>` tags when they're on the same line - that is the problem.